# Brackeys Player Motor script doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### The Problem

I'm following the Brackeys multiplayer tutorial and I got stuck in episode 2. I wrote the script just like in the video, no errors but I still cant look around. This script is put onto a 3D blender-made model. this is the code V

### The Code

```
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// gets a movement vector
public void Move(Vector3 _velocity)
{
    velocity = _velocity;
}

// gets a rotational vector
public void Rotate(Vector3 _rotation)
{
    rotation = _rotation;
}

//run every physics iteration
void FixedUpdate()
{
    PerformMovement();
    PerformRotation();
}

//perform movement based on velocity variable
void PerformMovement()
{
    if(velocity != Vector3.zero)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}

//Perform rotation
void PerformRotation()
{
    rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rotation));
}
```

}

Comment: Everything shown here is the question looks adequate. My best guess is that you aren't setting something up to call `Rotate` correctly. See [mre] and consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Sorry for the unprofessional question. but I found the problem, i just had to restart unity and recreate the scripts.